# Force a browser to link to a fresh copy of a pdf every time?

Tags: html, url, href, page-refresh

Let's say I have something like

```
<a href="https://example.com/schedule.pdf">download me</a>
```

The `schedule.pdf` file changes frequently on the back end, and I want the user to always get the most recent copy.

The page this is on is static, so adding a random ?[somerandomnumber] to the end of the URL is not feasible, and in any case, the page itself may be cached on the browser, so the user wouldn't necessarily see a new version of the page with the link on it.

Is there anything I can put in that  statement (or at least nearby, inline) that will make sure it downloads a fresh copy of the pdf?

I'm dealing with an antiquated CMS outside my control, so I can't shove anything into a meta header or even muck with the CSS files.  I'm looking for an inline solution.  Any kind of special OnClick magic I can throw in there?

Additionally, is there any browser-agnostic method of making sure putting `https://example.com/schedule.pdf` into a browser's URL bar will get the most recent copy, even if there's something in the local browser cache right now?

I do actually have control of the Apache config on the server, so I could make a system-wide change.

The PDF is the only thing I want to make sure is fresh.  I am not trying to make sure every object or page is un-cached, and I'm not trying to force the PDF to be downloaded instead of viewed within the browser.  I'm just trying to make sure when you click that link or manually put in the file's URL that you're getting the most recent copy of the file, even if there's something sitting in your local browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

----- Complete Code for Auto Update Download link With PHP -----

----- How To Make A Fresh / Auto Updated Download Link With PHP -----

Create a folder called "pdf_folder" on the same location of this php file and set a PDF file in it,

You can Download the code from here: https://eetsceeck.cf/pdf_script/

Here is the full code:

```
<?php


// ============================================= LEAVE ME ALONE DONT TOUCH ME 
// DEFINE DEFAULT VARY (AVOID UNDEFINE VARIABLES ERRORS)
$PDF_FOR_DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME = "";


// DEFINE THE PATH OF THE PDF FOLDER
//
$PDF_Folder_location = "./pdf_folder/";
// ============================================= LEAVE ME ALONE DONT TOUCH ME 




// USE QUERY TO LOOK FOR THE LATEST FILE CREATED BY DATE AND TIME FUNCTION
// AS WELL FETCH THE FILE NAME
//
FUNCTION Get_latest_file ($PDF_Folder_location) {
    

// ARRANGE PDF IN ARRAY FOR SORTING

$OPEN_dir = opendir($PDF_Folder_location); // = > PDF directory


// WHILE LOOP - IF THERE ARE PDF'S GET THEM //=>
// 
    WHILE (false !== ($PDF_file = readdir($OPEN_dir))) {
    if (strstr($PDF_file,".pdf"))
        
    // IF EXIST EXECUTE A LIST BY DATE/TIME - FETCH TO ARRAY ALL INFO DATE/TIME=>NAME
    // ARRAY
    $PDF_file_list[] = DATE("YmdHis ", FILEMTIME($PDF_Folder_location.$PDF_file)).$PDF_Folder_location.$PDF_file; 

} // <= END OF WHILE LOOP

// SORT RESULTS OF ARRAY
//
rsort($PDF_file_list);
// 
// END OF FETCH


// DEFINE VARY FOR FILENAME ONLY TO BE EXECUTED AS LINK PATH TO FILE
echo $PDF_FOR_DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME = BASENAME($PDF_file_list[0]); // (USE ME FOR YOUR HTML LINK TO YOUR PDF DOWNLOAD BUTTON)

} // END OF FUNCTION FOR LATEST PDF FILE

?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PDF file download</title>


<style>
html,
body,
#container {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
body {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   color: #000000;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: normal;
   line-height: 1.1875;
   margin: 0;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   padding: 0;
}
#PDF_file_download_btn {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   background-color: #000000;
   background-image: none;
   border: 0px solid #2E6DA4;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
   font-size: 21px;
   font-weight: normal;
   line-height: 60px;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: top;
}
#PDF_file_download_btn:hover {
   -moz-transition: background-color 100ms linear 0ms;
   -webkit-transition: background-color 100ms linear 0ms;
   background-color: #FF0000;
   transition: background-color 100ms linear 0ms;
}
#PDF_file_download_btn {
   -moz-transition: all 100ms linear 0ms;
   -webkit-transition: all 100ms linear 0ms;
   transition: all 100ms linear 0ms;
}
#container {
   background-color: #FBFBFB;
   background-image: none;
}
#container {
   height: 330px;
   left: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
}
#container_Container {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   position: relative;
   text-align: left;
   width: 800px;
}
#PDF_file_download_btn {
   height: 60px;
   left: 225px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 135px;
   width: 350px;
   z-index: 0;
}
a {
   color: #0000FF;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
   color: #800080;
}
a:active {
   color: #FF0000;
}
a:hover {
   color: #0000FF;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
input:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
   outline: none;
}
.visibility-hidden {
   visibility: hidden;
}
h1,
.h1 {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #000000;
   display: inline;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 32px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
h2,
.h2 {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #000000;
   display: inline;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 27px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
h3,
.h3 {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #000000;
   display: inline;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
h4,
.h4 {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #000000;
   display: inline;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
h5,
.h5 {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #000000;
   display: inline;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 19px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
h6,
.h6 {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #000000;
   display: inline;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.CustomStyle {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #2E74B5;
   font-family: "Courier New";
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="container_Container">
     





<!-- i am here for test purposes only you can delete me no issue with that -->   
<?php
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo 'i am your newest pdf file and my name is:';
echo '<br>';
echo Get_latest_file($PDF_Folder_location); 
?>




<br>
<br>

<!--                                            i am here to echo the whole 
                                                function so your file name 
                                                will be available to download 
                                                so you cannot delete me, you need me!
-->
<a id="PDF_file_download_btn" href="./pdf_folder/<?php echo Get_latest_file($PDF_Folder_location); ?>" title="My dummy pdf file - download me">

Dummy PDF file Download

</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...just trying to figure out the actual implementation here...I'd put the text in a whatever.php file on the server and use that in the href instead of whatever.pdf, or would I put the full `<?PHP echo $PDF_FOR_DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME; ? >` thing in there? I ask because the CMS is very restrictive and I'm not sure it would let that go through. It already constantly reformats my margins and such.  Using a static filename and replacing the file constantly is already a hack to try to defeat it. Even getting the php on the server might require a trick.

Comment: Updated Original answer. please check the full code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be rude, I just haven't had the time to test this appropriately.  I do appreciate your effort.  I think the effort you put into making the script modular and useful for future Googlers of this question has made it more complex for me to understand.  When I have the time to truly examine it, I will give it the attention it deserves. I just didn't want you to feel like you've been ignored.  Your good work will not go to waste, as these questions will stay documented here for a long time.  Thanks again, and I hope to have a proper response soon!

Comment: OK, I still don't understand what you're trying to do with this code.  Are you trying to select the most recent PDF from a list of PDFs in a given folder?  Because that's not what I'm trying to do. I have one single file which always has the same name, but that file might change.  When it does change, most browsers will not automatically reload it.  I want it to be reloaded every time it's clicked on.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is possible simply with htaccess, you can configure the pdf files to be cached for a minute, i thought you will upload new file every time you update the pdf, 
my code is still valid for you cause even if you will update the same file name the php will update it for you, cause now its not depends on any cache, it depends on the file hash which the php will update for you, you can test it, just download the full code, insert a pdf file with title "pdf 1", download it, and then insert the another pdf with the same name, with another title for instance "pdf

Comment: yes! i just tested it on my server and its updating the file automatically with the same name, as i said it depends on hash and time, so you dont have even to mess with htaccess,

Comment: Inserting an .htaccess file is easier than trying to get the CMS to let me run a php file.  The CMS filters out attempts to use anything other than regular links.  I'll try an .htaccess with a short cache timeout and see how it works, although I don't think all browsers interpret those files the same way. Also I should note that I can't modify the header of the original html file.

Comment: well, you did ask for an auto update link solution, i was assume you have access to the cms files and you have basic knowledge in php, the implementation of this supposed to be easy, the code comes in anywhere on the system and the variable need to be replaced with the original variable, but if you can use htaccess for this it should be enough, what matters is the most browsers in use, and all of them accept caching commands.

Comment: well, you did ask for an auto update link solution, i was assume you have access to the cms files and you have basic knowledge in php, the implementation of this supposed to be easy, the code comes in anywhere on the system and the variable need to be replaced with the original variable, but if you can use htaccess for this it should be enough, what matters is the most browsers in use, and all of them accept caching commands.